# If we browse context path, Internal jaxws endpoint should not visible with context path on the browser

Tags: apache-camel

Thank you in advance.

Can you please give me possible solution to fix below problem.

Problem is  internal jaxws endpoint should not visible on the bowser, when we browse context path(ex: http://localhost:8080/cws-finance/services).

   service name is PaymentWs. PaymentWs service has two version’s(1.1,1.2) of wsdls.
   We created two external cxf endpoints and one jaxws internal end point.
   First external endpoint interact  with 1.1 version wsdl and second external endpoint interact with 1.2 version wsdl
   Internal jaxws endpoint interact with java code(serviceImpl)
   We are using camel routing to route external endpoints to internal endpoint. 
   If I browse context path(ex: http://localhost:8080/cws-finance/services). I can view two are external endpoints and one is internal endpoint on the browser.
   As per requirement , internal endpoint should not view on the browser. Only two external endpoints should be visible.
   I am doing migration from service mix bundle to web application(war) deploying in tomcat. In servicemix ,it was working as per requirement. This requirement was achieved in servicemix  by using NMR api with JBI container.

Internal jaxws endpoint configuration:

```
            <jaxws:endpoint id="paymentWS" implementor="#paymentWSImp"
                            endpointName="tns:PaymentWSPort" address="/nmr/PaymentWS/1.2/Port"
                            serviceName="tns:PaymentWSService" xmlns:tns="http://www.centurytel.com/PaymentWS">
                            <jaxws:features>
                                            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
                            </jaxws:features>
                            <jaxws:properties>
                                            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
                            </jaxws:properties>
            </jaxws:endpoint>
```

External cxf endpoints configurations:

```
 <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="paymentWS_1_1" address="/PaymentWS/1.1/Port"
                            endpointName="s:PaymentWSPort" serviceName="s:PaymentWSService"
                            wsdlURL="wsdl/paymentws_1.1.wsdl" xmlns:s="http://www.centurytel.com/PaymentWS">
                            <cxf:properties>
                                            <entry key="dataFormat" value="MESSAGE" />
                            </cxf:properties>
            </cxf:cxfEndpoint>


            <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="paymentWS_1_2" address="/PaymentWS/1.2/Port"
                            endpointName="s:PaymentWSPort" serviceName="s:PaymentWSService"
                            wsdlURL="wsdl/paymentws_1.2.wsdl" xmlns:s="http://www.centurytel.com/PaymentWS">
                            <cxf:properties>
                                            <entry key="dataFormat" value="MESSAGE" />
                            </cxf:properties>
            </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Camel routing:

```
            <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

                            <route id="paymentWS_1_1_route">
                                            <from uri="cxf:bean:paymentWS_1_1" />
                                            <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
                                            <convertBodyTo type="javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource" />
                                            <to uri=" http://localhost:8080/cws-finance/services /nmr/PaymentWS/1.2/Port"/>
                                            <process ref="PaymentWS_1_1_ProxyOutProc" />
                                            <to uri="log:input" />
                            </route>


                            <route id="paymentWS_1_2_route">
                                            <from uri="cxf:bean:paymentWS_1_2" />
                                            <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
                                            <convertBodyTo type="javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource" />
                                            <to uri=" http://localhost:8080/cws-finance/services /nmr/PaymentWS/1.2/Port"/>
                                            <to uri="log:input" />
                            </route>

            </camelContext>
```

Comment: can you please give me the possible solution as soon as possible.

Comment: a) You can use below property on internal endpoint to hide it and route the requests from external end points to it.

              <jaxws:properties>
                     <entry key="org.apache.cxf.endpoint.private" value="true"/>
              </jaxws:properties>